# mysql 5.0 rank function

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySql 5.0 as i search the internet i can see many people talking about the rank function but as i try it on MySql 5.0 which I'm using it doesn't really work.  For example:
`SELECT RANK() OVER (order by total_time desc)as rank , id ,first name ,last name
from user_tbl;`
     But this line of query doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rank function in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql)

Comment: mysql does not have a rank() function.

Comment: i only want to display the rank of the last user(id) can anyone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not support `RANK()` function, or any of the other analytic functions supported by other databases like Oracle and SQL Server.